# How to Impersonate different users in different directories in linq query?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, .net-4.0

I am trying to Impersonate different users in order to find differences between two directories. This is my Code, but i get Access denied when the query executes. Notice that the users are correct and the above impersonation works when both DirectoryInfo executes.

```
  Dim impersonateUser As New UserImpersonation
            impersonateUser.impersonateUser("user1", "", "password1")
            Dim dir1 = New DirectoryInfo("\\10.11.11.122\OnDemand Recordings")
            impersonateUser.undoimpersonateUser()

            impersonateUser.impersonateUser("user2", "", "password2")
            Dim dir2 = New DirectoryInfo("\\10.11.11.172\OCDialer_Recordings\OnDemand")
            impersonateUser.undoimpersonateUser()

'In this Block i get access denied
            Dim filesinboth = From f1 In dir1.EnumerateFiles(System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                  Join f2 In dir2.EnumerateFiles(System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories) On f1.Name Equals f2.Name
                  Select f1.Name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That impersonation probably sets credentials for the current thread, and that's why you get the access-denied error - as the 2nd impersonation overwrites the 1st (and you can't have more than one user running a single thread/app at the same time).

Try this:

This will work only if you are comparing relatively small amount of information about each file/dir (e.g. their names). Read [full] paths to directories and files into a list or some sort of tree-like/recursive collection (you can create something like the class below for the latter).

```
class dir
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<dir> dirs { get; set; }
    public string files { get; set; }
}
```

Or simply store full paths to `List<string>` (same case for easier comparison).

Then, read the complete directories separately. Compare them later. Store differences in 3rd list.